# Angular: How to retrieve DOM element after adding a model to a collection

Tags: angularjs

I have a table where users can keep adding rows by clicking on a link. That link is tied to a function that adds an object to an array. I want to be able to retrieve the DOM element that is being generated but can't figure out how to do this. I generate a DOM element ID but if I use jQuery to retrieve it it still doesn't exist when I do it in the function that adds the model.

Thanks for your ehlp

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <td>{{row.name}}</td>
    <td>{{row.age}}</td>
</tr>

<a class="button small" ng-click="addRow();">Add Row</a>

$scope.addRow = function() {    
    $scope.rows.push({name: 'blah',age: 12});
    // how do i get the dom element?
}
```

Comment: post some code please

Comment: What do you want to do with the dom element? Why do you want it? The angular way would be to do whatever you want to do with the DOM element by passing in values to the array the same way you are passing name and age. For example, you could pass a class or id or even css values and have the table's directive initialize the new row with those values

Comment: I want to retrieve the element and get the first cell. Eventually I'll have an input field in there and want to be able to focus on it upon adding the element.

Answer (score 0):

Often if you need access to the DOM in your controller/scope methods you are not doing it the "Angular way", I would recommend you do this work with a Directive instead.

Comment: Thanks. In my case I want to get the first cell of the newly added row so not sure how I would do this in a directive. STill learning about Angular so I'll look at the docs

Comment: @user1732055 No problem, so think about it this way, if you put a directive on the cell element that you need to do something with/to of your row template in you ng-repeat you will get access to it upon creation of the element.